# go: which of channels endpoints has to close the channel when its bidirectional?

Tags: go, channel

Due to Go's philosophy a channel should be closed by the sender only. When a channel is bidirectional where should it be closed?

Comment: At the endpoint where it is created.

Comment: If there's no clear point where the channel should be closed, why are you closing it?

Comment: Having a clear point of where the channel should be closed would also mean to notify the other endpoint so it won't send any new messages to it, right? Thats the problem which seems to be solved pretty well with the paradigm that the sender should close the channel... so the only way to solve is to not use bidirectional channels.

Comment: If both participants may signal "no more messages", that warrants 2 channels (or other means, e.g. special "no more messages" message).

Comment: The sender closes the channel. A receiver with a bidirectional channel should not close the channel.

Comment: you're not forced to close a channel in Go, there's nothing wrong with let it open

Comment: Writing to or closing a closed channel will panic, so if both sides are potentially senders, you need to recover from those potential crashes.

Even if you check that the channel is still open before writing, there's still a race condition unless you use a mutex, which kind of defeats the point. A select statement will sometimes panic (the spec is ambiguous about what should happen, seems to depend on lexical order: [1](https://play.golang.org/p/0oLAx68sX3) [2](https://play.golang.org/p/SWewpj40xv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little bit hard to interpret since go does not have bidirectional channels. Data flows only in a single direction - from a writer to a reader.

What you can have in Go is multiple readers or writers on a channel. Whether this makes sense depends a little bit on the context. If you have multiple writers you would need some kind of synchronization for the close operation, e.g. a mutex. However you would then also need to lock this before each write operation in order to ensure that you don't write on a closed channel. If you don't really need the information that the channel was closed on receiver side you could also simply omit the close, as the garbage collector will also collect unclosed channels just fine.

Comment: Surely golang channels are bidirectional, even the language spec states that they are (unless you specify a direction as part of its type)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and besides the statement, that go doesnt have bidirectional channels you got some interesting input here. I didnt knew that the garbage collector would collect unclosed channels because I thought they could not be forced to be closed from the outside. It doesnt feel good to not have control over what exactly happens so I stay with using channels strictly in a single-direction way and open up two for such purposes.